# How can I change the way VS 2013 formats Razor inline code?

Tags: formatting, visual-studio, code, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I format a Razor document (via Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D), sections that have inline code, such as this, are pulled to the left.

How can I stop or change it?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Visual Studio Format options ?

Comment: I guarantee you;  This is a setting within Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, if it is, hopefully someone will post an answer with what it's called, since I can't seem to find it.

Comment: That's a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in Tools > Options > Text Editor, but I doubt there is much you can configure there for Razor.